# Setting a toolbar in a List Activity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-toolbar

I have a ListActivity that I want to use the toolbar in but I get the error can't resolve getSupportToolbar. Everything works fine in my main activity but here I get errors.

Comment: The [source of ListActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java) shows very small actual implementation. Maybe it is time to stop using `ListActivity`? There is [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html), which works great alongside [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this excerpt on an Android dev blog post. You have to use the toolbar as a standalone object and add your own items.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle the menu item
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you haven't set the toolbar in your activity. First you have to set the app theme to`@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, 
Then you have to set the custom toolbar in your MainActivity like
     
     `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_main_activity);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     TextView toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title_toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);`

I hope this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I had set up a toolbar in my List Activity. I will post the layout file details

activity1.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_activity"  />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

</LinearLayout>


toolbar_activity.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonReturn"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```